# random click to keep session alive selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

How do I do a random click somewhere on the page after n seconds to keep the session alive while using selenium? Scraping is going on, if we don't do something it will disconnect the session. Is there any other way to do some activity/keep the session alive?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import json
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('URL')
time.sleep(15)
def find_button():
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/main/div[1]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/iframe"))
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/button')))
        if button:
            button.click()
    except TimeoutException as e:
        pass
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#root > div.css-1dskt1c.ev4oou50 > main > div.css-fxcew.eqhy1wt0 > div.css-1o0ko6s.ejzudwb1 > div.css-wp7h99.ebewhpb0 > section.css-n56t2b.e1bk88wc2 > header > div.css-8hdyh3.esmanvo0 > svg'))).click()
    while True:
        info = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div.css-1dskt1c.ev4oou50 > main > div.css-fxcew.eqhy1wt0 > div.css-1o0ko6s.ejzudwb1 > div.css-wp7h99.ebewhpb0 > section.css-conr1v.e1bk88wc2 > div > div > div.css-1t6u4d1.ezcyhjn1 > div.css-r8tf41.eyg06i70')
        result = info.text
        result = result.replace('\n', ' ')
        time.sleep(5)
        dictionary = {"1st 12": result[6:22], "2nd 12": result[30:46]}
        json_dump = json.dumps(dictionary)
        print(json_dump)

find_button()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perform a click using selenium you can follow these two steps. When your program starts, create a thread or a another process which keeps clicking after each **n seconds**. You can easily do this by making use of python threading module or multiprocessing module.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("myelement")
element.click()
```

Although another suggestion would be to make use of **headless** while using selenium.

Comment: Just one question..I tried this for closing a reoccuring pop-up. When I call 2 functions using Threading..it opens a new chrome window..How to take care of that?

Comment: I am still debugging so I need to see what's going on, how will `--headless` help though?

Comment: @AbhishekRai Try passing the same object instance as the object to the other thread. In case it does not work, try porting it to multiprocessing from multithreading. Also it would be really helpful if we could have a look at the code. Since it's hard to recommend based on just textual description. Could you please share the code as well.

Comment: let me do that.

Comment: . Added the code. I tried making the button click a different function and scraping a different one and called them with If main ..Thread target=find_button etc..However, only 1st function worked, the second one opened a new window not knowing what to do because, I assumed `driver` would be on the same page. I guess that isn't the case.

Comment: @AbhishekRai could you share the complete code please. That way I could copy and run it on my machine and try to debug.